# Lifting representation Heisenberg algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-group

I (think) I've found the Heisenberg Lie algebra representation through quantization. Where we have $q \mapsto q$ and  $p \mapsto -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial q}$.

So this is only a Lie algebra representation. $\rho_*:  \mathfrak{h} \to \text{End}(V)  $.

Where $V$ is the hilbert space (representation space).  And $\mathfrak{h}$ is the Heisenberg Lie algebra.

How do I lift this to a lie group representation $\rho: H \to \text{Gl}(V)$ .
Where $H$ is the Heisenberg group?  And how do I show it's unitary?

Answer (score 2):

You are representing the three algebra elements $q, p, 1\!\!1$ by hermitian operators acting on functions of *q*. For simplicity, non-dimensionalize $\hbar=1$--only the clueless keep it unscaled.

Multiplying linear combinations of such operators by *i* and exponentiating yields the generic unitary [group element representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Representation_theory) for you ,
$$
e^{ic + ibq + a\partial_q} ~ f(q) =  e^{ic + iab/2} e^{ibq} e^{a\partial_q} ~f(q)=     e^{ic + iab/2 +ibq}~ f(q+a),
$$
for real coefficients *a, b, c*, the standard form used routinely in applications.

The first equality is a bland application of the [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) ("inverse Campbell-Baker-Haussdorf"), and the second equality is using up the Lagrange [shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) involved.

Comment: is f(q) the element of the hilbert space? Where the action of exponential is simply multiplying?

Comment: And what is the degree of the representation?

Comment: Yes your algebra rep acts on functions of q. Yes, surviving exponential is mere multiplication. Infinite degree.

Comment: thank you! What about the irreducibility. How would you prove it?

Comment: Oohhhh.. it is a [long story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem)... real long... another question...

Comment: However, when you fill in a group element from the heisenberg group. So let's say we have g =(a,b,c) in the Heisenberg group, and pi the representation.  What will pi(a,b,c) be. How would you know the coefficients in the exponent?

Comment: And why did del q suddenly remove?

Comment: I analyzed the generic group element by use of the Zassenhaus formula, and then "used up" the *b* gradient in shifting the arument of the "vector" *f(q)* acted upon!